# Vue child component didn't rerender when props changed?

Tags: vue.js, components, vuex

In my application, I use vuex to manage my component state,when state changes with 
vuex mutations,the child component didn't rerender.
Here's my code on CodeSandbox:https://codesandbox.io/s/l3lrwv6yll

When I clicked header in **blue area** to add item to **red area**,the mutation works.But when I clicked the edit button, the computed property in my Header component didn't change.

Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your mutation `editField` you should use `Vue.set` to detect changes in array :

```
   editField(state, { index }) {
      let update = state.formFieldList[index];
      Vue.set(state.formFieldList, index, {
        name: update.name,
        schema: {
          ...update.schema,
          edit: true
        }
      })
    },
```

Check Vue docs - [Array Changing Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)